# Configure Solr to reject index/update requests with later timestamp (in the document)

Tags: solr

While replaying documents (to cover for indexing holes), it is possible for my solr server to receive indexing reqests from two sources at the same time; and one of those sources will have an older copy of the document. I have `lastModified` timestamp in my solr documents. How can I use it to skip indexing the document if its recent copy has already been indexed (by the other stream)?

I am considering to modify `UpdateHandler` and read the document before indexing (when more than one indexing 'streams' are in progress). I am not sure if this is a viable approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [your timestamps with DocBasedVersionConstraintsProcessorFactory](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-In-PlaceUpdates) and ignoreOldUpdates set. That seems to match your use-case exactly, as described in the Solr Reference Guide.

Comment: Great answer :)